# Partial não renderiza com 'enter' usando Ajax

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Tenho um ajax que é disparado quando a página é carregada:

`/assets/javascript/itens.js`:

```
if ($('#content-recommendation').length) {
    xhr = $.ajax({
    url:'/get_recommendations/' + gon.item_id + '.js',
    type:"get"
  });
}
```

`views/items/show`:

```
<div id="content-recommendation" class="col-md-3">
  <p>hey!</p>
</div>
```

`itens_controller#get_recommendation`:

```
def get_recommendations
  respond_to do |format|
     format.js
  end
end
```

`itens/get_recommendations.js.erb`:

```
$("#content-recommendation").html("<%= render 'content_recommendation'%>")
```

`_content_recommendation.html.erb`:

```
<h3>Ultimos itens visitados:</h3>
<p>teste</p>
```

Este é de longe o problema mais estranho que encontrei em RoR. Se coloco em `_content_recommendation.html.erb`:

```
<h3>Ultimos itens visitados:</h3><p>teste</p>
```

(sem espaços) ele funciona...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em `get_recommendations.js.erb` estava faltando `escape_javacript`:

```
$("#content-recommendation").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'content_recommendation', itens: @itens_recomendados ) %>")
```

Tem mais informações neste [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620113/why-escape-javascript-before-rendering-a-partial)

Comment: Awkward, considere marcar sua resposta como correta, clicando do lado esquerdo, abaixo da pontuação. Obrigado!